How to graphically draw stars using python and AAVSO data
I have a file containing information about stars that looks like this for each star:
010001 |R     And *|002401.95 +383437.3 |M
and i need to figure out a way to converted so i can graphically show starts with dots on screen

Can you give more details on what you have tried and what you already know.  002401.95 +383437.3 means a right ascension of 00 hours, 24 minutes and 01.95 seconds and +383437.3 means a declension of +34 degrees 24 minutes and 37.3 seconds.  That's like latitude and longitude.  Does that answer your question?

Which coordinate system is that and is it +34 degrees from the center?

002401.95 +383437.3 means a right ascension of 00 hours, 24 minutes and 01.95 seconds and +383437.3 means a declension of +34 degrees 24 minutes and 37.3 seconds.
The sky is a sphere, with the Earth at the centre.  The poles of the Earth can be projected onto the sky, and so can the equator
The declension is like the "latitude". It measures the angle from the projected equator. It is measured in degrees, arcminutes, arcseconds (sixty minutes = 1 degree)
The right ascension is the "longitude".  It is measured in hours-minutes-seconds.  As there are 24 hours in 360 degrees, you must multiply by 15 to convert to degrees.
These are the two angles and a point on a sphere, but as your screen in flat, you'll need a map projection to plot on the screen.  All projections introduce distortions and so there isn't a "right" way to do this. Plane-Carré is simple, you plot the right ascension as x and decension as y, but it creates large distortion near the poles.

Declination, rather than declension?
